# do marginal density functions derived from a joint pdf always integrate to 1 (are they valid pdf's)?

Tags: density-function, marginal-distribution

If I have a joint pdf of multiple random variables, say 3 for simplicity, $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$, is it true that the marginal density functions derived from that joint probability distribution ( $f_{X}(x)$, $f_{Y}(y)$, $f_{Z}(z)$ ) are not guaranteed to be valid probability density functions (integrate to 1) in all cases. I can see that the pdf condition holds for the marginals when the random variables are independent but not quite sure what happens when we introduce dependence between them.

Comment: By definition, a marginal distribution describes a subset of the random variables and *must* be a valid distribution.  If you do a calculation that violates that condition, then you have erred.

Comment: I just realized that my claim is equivallent to saying that the volume under the joint distribution is not 1. So dumb...

Comment: @Statisticool For closure purposes, you may want to well answer it yourself and accept your own answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Using two properties of the joint pdf: 
$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y, z) \, dx \, dy \, dz = 1$,
and $f_X(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y, z) \, dy \, dz$ 
It follows that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) \, dx = 1$

Comment: Notice this assumes Fubini's Theorem applies.  But you don't need it: *the marginal density is that of the variable $X,$* namely, the one obtained by *forgetting about all the other variables.*  It's that simple!